# WiFi does not turn on

Tags: 10.10, networking, dv6

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.10 along side of my HP pavilion dv6 windows 7. For what ever reason it states that there is no hard ware for the WiFi and it is disabled. The only way for it to work is to have the WiFi on during windows then reboot it ( which is very unproductive) Is there any fix for it?

Comment: So, you turn it on in Windows, reboot it into Ubuntu and it works.  For how long?  When does it *stop* working again.

Comment: Different models of DV6 have different cards - can you post the result of `lspci | grep -i net` into your answer (not as a comment).  That will help people diagnose the fault.

Answer (score 1):

Have you toggled the hardware wifi radio button?

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: Looks like older versions of Ubuntu had problems with the button (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1173984).  Don't know if that's fixed now.

Comment: @Del page 11 of the document here shows where the wireless button is: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01758220.pdf